# typeorm Ilike but only for string array

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a user with skills

```
@Entity("users")
export class UserEntity {
@Column('text', { array: true, nullable: true, })
skills: string[]
}
```

and I need to look for users who have certain skills

but I need the search to be partial match, for example when using ILike("%${query}%") but only for an array

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to partially search in an array of strings :

```
SELECT *
FROM "users"
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM unnest("skills") s
  WHERE s LIKE '%${searchString}%'
);
```

`unnest` function breaks the array into the individual strings elements upon which we perform our search.

The `typeorm` query for the above sql statement would be:

```
const users = await this.userRepo.createQueryBuilder('user')
      .where('EXISTS(SELECT * FROM unnest("user"."skills") s WHERE s LIKE :searchString)', {
        searchString: `%${searchString}%`,
      })
      .getMany();
```

(here `searchString` variable is the skill with which you want to perform the partial search)